# Swift add UIViews dynamicly based on array of objects

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, storyboard

So what I am trying to do is to add as many UIViews as there are companies. I want to "copy and paste" and already existing UIView with the information of the company in a horizontal stack view.

As you can see in the picture I have a "allCompaniesShow" that is the horizontal stack view where I want to add multiple UIViews (companyShow). And for each UIView(CompanyShow) I want to show the company name

[image]

I have initialised them in the controller

```
@IBOutlet weak var allCompaniesShow: UIStackView!
@IBOutlet weak var companyName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var companyShow: UIView!
```

I am making the companies like this in my viewDidLoad()

```
let companies = [
            Company(owner: "jan"),
            Company(owner: "henk"),
        ]
```

And this is how I loop throuugh the array of object to make new views

```
for company in companies {
            companyName.text = company.owner
            allCompaniesShow.addArrangedSubview(companyShow)
        }
```

What happens is it's just showing one view with "henk" as owner

Could you please tell me how to make as many views as there are companies based on the already existing view?

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` be easier? Otherwise, you could create a NIB file for your "Company Show" view and load an instance for each company or you could create the sun view entirely in code.

Comment: I do not know, I am pretty new to swift. And I am trying to show the companies in "boxes" in a horizontal scrollview @Paulw11

Comment: `UICollectionView` in a scroll view then.

Comment: Okay i'm going to try UicollectionView thanks for the answer!

Comment: Reason of showing one view is because of the width of stack view.
Add a scroll view inside `allCompaniesShow` and take care of autolayouts.

Comment: No, there is only one view because there is only one instance of the "Company Show" view in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UITableView for this case.

1- just add a tableView of the same size as your stack and give it a cell

2-and add protocols UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource to your UIViewcontroller

3-make `tableView.delegate = self` and `tableView.datasource = self` in your viewDidLoad method. Alternatively you can add those from storyboard

4-use "numberOfRowsInSection" function to return how many rows you want,in your case return the number of counts of companies

5- and lastly use "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method for cells